# I/O error while cp from CD to HDD

Tags: linux, kernel, cp, io

I'm trying to create a local repo from my RHEL6 disk.  Some of the .rpms I'm able to copy, others give me this error:

```
cp: reading 'filename': Input/Output error
```

It's the original RedHat disk, and it has no scratches. I can't believe that's the CD.
I'm running a VirtualBox machine.

This is what I get at `/var/log/messages`:

> kernel: attempt to access beyond end of device
>   kernel: sr0: rw=0, want 4303160, limit 2097148
>   kernel: Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block: 1075789

Any idea what could be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Are those /var/log/messages lines from the VM guest or the host?

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you try to copy the same files on the host?

Comment: Thats the /var/log/messages from the VM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem isn't a faulty disc, it could be a bad optical drive, data cable, or some other underlying problem with your system (CPU / RAM / power problems).

Comment: I think there was a problem with the VM Machine. what I did what restoring to an earlier snapshot, and tried to copy those files manually (not using wildcards). Now, it works. :)